# Passing filter to directive from controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive called `myCustomDirective` and it takes a list of value and a filter function.

```
myapp.directive('myCustomDirective', function ($rootScope) {
     return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            values: "=",
            customfilter: "&"
          },
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/template.html',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
        }
    }
});
```

And in my directive template `template.html`, I have a simple list which will be filtered as filter function the directive got from client code.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in values | filter:customFilter>
       <td ng-repeat="key in displaykey">{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In my controller, the custom function is

```
$scope.myCustomFilter = function(value)
{
  return function(item)
   {
     if(item.name contains value) return true;
     return false;
    }
}
```

From HTML of client code, I want to pass the value and function by which the directive will filter the list.

```
<div>
  <my-custom-directive customfilter="myCustomFilter("a")"></my-custom-directive>
</div>
```

How can I get it right?

Comment: So, what is the problem? What's not working? Any error messages?

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash No error actually, but the list is not filtered as expected.

Comment: Its good to do filtering in directive itself , rather than in html  and making code complex